# Weird nosense CCSpriteBatchNode Exception

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

There is something weird going on in my cocos2d game I can't figure out the problem.

I have a very simple files structure for my game, 1 intro layer, 1 main menu layer, 1 game layer.

While I was developing I skiped the menu layer in order for the game jump from intro layer to save time.

Now I finished the game, I added back the main menu and when game layer is called from it it crashes!!??

it never crashes if I skip the main menu layer.

Edit:

Important, If I have remove the main menu layer it works just fine... main menu doesn't add any texture atlas, there is only one I am using entire the whole game.

this is the message error:

```
"CCSprite: Batched sprites should use the same texture as the batchnode"
```

from this gamelayer code:

```
_myitens = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"mytextureatlas.png";
```

The funny thing is Main menu Layer only feature is to have a button(image from file and not texture atlas) that calls the game layer....

it is very confusing I can't see how to approach this issue

any tips are valid thanks

Comment: add an exception breakpoint, you'll find the exact line of the problem, then you can check which texture and sprite frame the sprite is using

Comment: I did add it, the exception is fired in my playable sprite on setDisplayFrame overwrite when I call the base class of it [super setDisplayFrame:paramFrame];

Comment: can't identify the frame with problem, using cocos2d 2.x

Answer (score 0):

One of the more common causes, and in particular if the problem depends on which scene you load first, occurs when you have the same image in two atlases.

For instance, assuming you have mytextureatlas.plist and notmytextureatlas.plist and both contain an image with the same name, say "player.png". If you first load mytextureatlas all seems fine. However when you load notmytextureatlas first, and later try to add a player.png sprite to the batch node using mytextureatlas, cocos2d will actually use the player.png from notmytextureatlas, provoking this error.

Double-check that all image names across all texture atlases are unique.

Comment: there is only one texture atlas in the game, if I remove the main menu layer it works fine

Comment: I'm really hopeless here, how come just 1 texture atlas in batchnode complaining about that...

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding sprites to `_myitems`? You are adding children which have been created with a different texture, that's the meaning of the error and that's what happening.

The exception is not non-sense, it means a precise condition which somewhere you fail to obey: **a batchnode must have children initialized with the same texture of the batchnode itself** (and it makes sense, since it's used to batch GL calls).

For example:

```
_myitems = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"mytextureatlas.png"];
[_myitems addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:@"othertexture.png"]];
```

Will generate the error. You should try with:

```
[_myitems addChild:[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:_myitems.textureAtlas.texture]];
```

Comment: all my texture are being used from the same batchnode, there is only one for the whole game. I add sprite to it just like that [_myitems addChild:_heroSprite];